# how to filter text from a string and convert it to dictionary and check for matching values in python

Tags: python, strings, hash-map

I am new to this community, I have tried this below code, this works fine, but looking for a better way of approaching for performance.

Please edit my question, it it is not understandable.

I have a string and list, I  need to filter that and converting that string to a dictionary , then if a dictionary key presents in the list, we need to append the corresponding dict[value] to my list

```
text='p.O(post office)\nR.J(Radio Jocky)'
list1=["R.J"]
text_splitted=text.split("\n")
my_dict={}
for item in text_splitted:
    index=item.index("(")
    key=item[:index]
    value=item[index+1:len(item)-1]
    my_dict[key]=value
list2=[my_dict[item] for item in my_dict.keys() if item in list1]
list1=list1+list2
output:
list1=['R.J', 'Radio Jocky']
```

Comment: What is your reasoning to convert it to a dictionary first, and afterwards convert it back to a list?

Comment: Are all values in the text like this `name(job)\n...`?

Comment: @Ludisposed ,  I a value present list1, i need to append the corresponding meaning to my list1, you can see my final output `R.J is already present in list1'  so im adding the meaning of `R.J` in the same list. To get this result im converting to dictionary and extracting the values. If there is any easy solution, please answer it

Comment: some values will have two parameters like `name(job,time)`

Comment: Please change the question title, 'how to' questions are off-topic here. And so shouldn't be a question title.

Comment: @Peilonrayz please edit my question as everyone can understand easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think the step of converting it to a list is unnecesarry, because we can check if it is in the list the same.
- I have a solution using regex to find the corresponding `name` and `job`
- You could use better variable names because `item` and `list1` `list2` are nondescriptive

*Note that using wilcards `.*` would be considered bad form in a regex*

You might want to change that to suit your needs.

---

```
from re import findall

def add_job(L, text):
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        name, job = findall(r"(.*)\((.*\))", line)[0]
        if name in L:
            L.append(job)
    return L

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text='p.O(post office)\nR.J(Radio Jocky)'
    list1=["R.J"]
    list1 = add_job(list1, text)
    print(list1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can you tell me the best resource to learn regex ?

Comment: https://regexone.com/ to learn and https://regex101.com/ to check your regular expressions

Comment: @pyd I know you are new here, my solution is far from optimal (I think) and you could maybe have a better one if you didnt accept on first sight. Codereview works a bit different then StackOverflow and I suggest to read [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/do-not-prematurely-accept-answers) meta post. And more on the meta to see the guidelines of Codereview. Have fun ^^

Comment: okay, I will wait for many solutions, from next question onward :D